# Google Analytics counter?

Tags: google-analytics, counter

I have read a lot of places that you can count using Google Analytics. I already use it on my site to track visitors.

How would I track how many people have clicked a spesific button and show the number of times it has been clicked on another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).  As far as displaying the results on another page, Google doesn't support showing charts/graphics outside of the Google Analytics site.  But you could find 3rd party app developers on the [Apps Gallery](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/) which do this.  I for one have created [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) for precisely this purpose.  And we also support dimension filtering so you could create a chart to show your specific action clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about the Google Analytics API at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference and even try it out interactively using http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

If you use Drupal you can easily install module [Google Analytics Counter](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter) that will automatically fetch and display pageviews collected by Google Analytics. Other CMS certainly have similar plugins.